# Android getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable() returns an empty Object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragmentactivity

I am attempting to send a Parcelable Object from one FragmentActivity to another.

The sending Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityToSendTo.class);
intent.putExtra("key", objectToSend);
startActivity(intent);
```

If I insert a breakpoint at this point I can see 'objectToSend' is populated and properties contain data.

The receiving Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentComments fragment = new FragmentComments();
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

If I insert a breakpoint in the onCreate method and try to view the objectToSend, I can see it exists but all properties on that object are now null.

Has anyone else experienced this? I think it must be a bug in the new support library perhaps?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that `FragmentComments` is the class that you want to pass to another `Activity`.
If that is the case then the code that retrieves the object should look more or less like that:

`Parcel parcel = (Parcel)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("key");`

Also make sure that `FragmentComments` correctly implements the `Parcelable` interface. More info on that topic is available at android.developer.com, [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: Sorry I may have mislead you, I am sending the Object `objectToSend` to the Activity `CommentsActivity`. `objectToSend` does indeed implement the `Parcelable` Interface.

The receiving Activity, `CommentsActivity` then gets `objectToSend` from the Intent extras and adds it to the arguments of the `CommentsFragment` which is displays by calling:
`getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();`

Comment: I'm convinced this is a bug. For now I have had to use use a static property to "pass" my object between Activities. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `objectToSend` extended from another class? If so in your `writeToParcel()` method, call `super.writeToParcel()` and pass it the parameters you have. Then in the constructor, be sure it takes in a Parcel object and call the `super()` constructor. So those two methods can look like

```
protected ObjectToSend(Parcel in){
    super(in);
    someNum = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeInt(someNum);
}
```

I was having the same problem and this fixed it right up! Hope it helps!